# Пунктуация - "в частности"

Tags: пунктуация, недопустимая-метка

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно ли выделять оборот "в частности" запятыми в этом случае? Или перед союзом нужна запятая. Совсем запуталась(

Болельщики и я в частности были в восторге!

Comment: Пока остановилась на данной версии.
Болельщики, и я в частности, были в восторге.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь выделяется запятыми весь присоединительный оборот "и я в частности":
"Болельщики, и я в частности, были в восторге!"

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: лучше, если вы кликнете на кисть с поднятым пальцем слева вверху

Comment: к сожалению, на данный момент у меня недостаточное количество "очков уважения".

Comment: Теперь достаточно.